# shuffle and split a data file into training and test set

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to shuffle and split a data file into a training set and test set using pandas and numpy, so I did the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

data_path = "/path_to_data_file/"

train = pd.read_csv(data_path+"product.txt", header=0, delimiter="|")
ts =  train.shape 
#print "data dimension", ts
#print "product attributes \n", train.columns.values 


#shuffle data set, and split to train and test set. 
df = pd.DataFrame(train)
new_train = df.reindex(np.random.permutation(df.index))

indice_90_percent = int((ts[0]/100.0)* 90)

print "90% indice", indice_90_percent

#write train products to csv 
#new_train.to_csv(sep="|")

with open('train_products.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in new_train[:indice_90_percent]:
        f.write(i+'\n')


with open('test_products.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in new_train[indice_90_percent:]:
        f.write(i+'\n')
```

But instead of getting the training and test files with data rows, I get two files containing the names of the columns. What did I miss?

Comment: you are iterating over the column names, the rows are in `new_train[indice_90_percent:].values`

Comment: it's because the iterable returned from a df are the columns and not the rows

Comment: @EdChum I would like to iterate over the rows, how to proceed?

Comment: Sorry you want to write to file each row or the entire df indexed by `indice_90_percent`?

Comment: @MedAli,you can use pandas to write 
`new_train[indice_90_percent:].to_csv('test_products.txt',header=False)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks. Please add your answer so I accept it.

Comment: @EdChum I wanted to split the file by the indice_90_percent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to write the rows, if you don't want the the column names use `header=False`.

```
new_train[indice_90_percent:].to_csv('test_products.txt',header=False)
new_train[:indice_90_percent].to_csv('train_products.txt',header=False)
```